# Generate urls for same product with different designs

Tags: seo, google, url, web-development, url-rewriting

How do you handle a product url when a brand has the same product type in different shapes?

Let me provide you with an example. I have Brand A that has sling bags. There is a sling bag, and there is a long sling bag. The shape and design of these 2 bags are totally different from each other.

Normally I would have a like like this:

```
www.exampel.com/product/1001/sling-bag
```

I was thing thinking in the line of:

`www.exampel.com/product/1001/sling-bag` and

```
www.exampel.com/product/1002/sling-bag
```

Then you have 2 different product URLs differentiated by their IDs. But to me this still looks almost like the same URL.

`www.exampel.com/product/1001/sling-bag` and

```
www.exampel.com/product/1002/long-sling-bag
```

..but I would prefer to keep a sling bag a sling bag.

Any suggestions? Will I be penalised by the search engines if I go for option 1?

I founf an example, same bags, same url except the ID is different:

```
http://www.cathkidston.com/shoulder-bags/double-handle-leather-bag-1016614

http://www.cathkidston.com/shoulder-bags/double-handle-leather-bag-1016613
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you're having different bags (e.g. photos), but you keep the same textual content, then it may seem as the pages are duplicates (because of textual content, that is one of the strongest signals to Google).

So, if the pages have the same (or nearly the same) text (page titles, meta descriptions, and on-page text) you should decide which of the pages you want to be the chosen one, and then on the other page place a canonical tag with an URL pointing to the chosen one.

If page titles, meta descriptions, and on-page text is different, then these two pages are good to go as independent pages.

Either way, you may use the scenario 1, as you wrote. But I'd suggest you to lean to the more descriptive URLs side, as semantically, long-sling-bag is more descriptive than sling-bag. And keywords in URLs have a bit of a SEO ranking power.

Answer (score 0):

As you said both products are different so I would also advise you to use unique content for both pages. Regarding URL Structure if you go with option 1 it will be fine, Google can't penalize you at all. But this type of URL structure is not user friendly and it will make your site less trustworthy. So it's better to use proper product name with the category in the URL like

```
www.example.com/bags/sling-bag
www.example.com/bags/long-sling-bag
```